# Does anyone have an example of a Tableau WDC accessing Agile Central (formerly Rally)?

Tags: rally, tableau-api

I have downloaded the Tableau SDK and am trying to get a coded example successfully pulling data from Agile Central.   Specifically I would like to be able to pull open work items in the current iteration or even better be able to choose the iteration to pull from.

Comment: Please show the code your having a problem with and the error your getting.

Comment: After much research and input from CA, it appears the WDC is not a recommended method for getting data with so much range and scope from Agile Central.    Suggestions have been to stick with some sort of ETL and datastore option.

Comment: Betsy E, does Agile Central support ETL's? My customer is migrating from Scrumwise to Agile central, and CA told us we needed to use the excel plugin to import data, and that ETL was not available.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but I did submit this Idea hoping that Rally would build the WDC for customers:

https://ideas.rallydev.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=FB85CCBC-A755-42AD-AF8E-6F2B539BECEC&idea_id=9F81C276-ABB7-4362-9D6E-BF9D7ADB250B

Answer (score 0):

Try this Web Data Connector built specifically to import Rally Data into Tableau for reporting

https://k504866430.github.io/rally-tableau/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. But anyway, your answer is more than appreciated. Thank you :)